# Highlight Links to the Current Page in a modularize website

Tags: php, css

I just want to add a `css` class named "active" to my navigation links when its page opened using php.

In my website the content have broken into  its individual components. And those components are separated, organized, and put back together using one index file. (website bootstrap file) Actually I am modularizing this website using php.

My Navigation is something similar to this code -

```
...

<li>
    <a href="index.php?p=dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="index.php?p=page-two">Page Two</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="index.php?p=page-three">Page Page Three</a>
</li>

...
```

This is how my index.php looks like -

```
// Validate what page to show:
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = $_GET['p'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['p'])) { // Forms
    $p = $_POST['p'];
} else {
    $p = NULL;
}

// Determine what page to display:
switch ($p) {

    case 'dashboard':
        $page = 'dashboard.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Control Panel';
        break;

    case 'page-three':
        $page = 'page-three.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Page Three';
        break;

    case 'page-two':
        $page = 'page-two.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Page Two';
        break;

    // Default is to include the main page.
    default:
        $page = 'login.inc.php';
                $page_title = 'Control Panel Login';
        break;

} // End of main switch.

// Make sure the file exists:
if (!file_exists('./modules/' . $page)) {
    $page = 'login.inc.php';
    $page_title = 'Control Panel Login';
}

include('./includes/header.html');

include('./modules/' . $page);

include('./includes/footer.html');
```

I have no idea how to add `active` css class dynamically to my links. hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: is that navigation part of `header.html`? maybe its time to make it a PHP so that you can use some of your variables and determine where to put that `active` using it.

Comment: @Ghost Yes navigation part is in header.html

Answer (score 0):

Compare the current file with the page to load using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

If they are equal:

```
case 'dashboard':
  $page = 'dashboard.inc.php';
  $page_title = 'Control Panel';
  $class == ($page == $p) ? 'active' : '';
break;
```

And add this class to HTML.

```
<li class="<?php echo $class;?>">
...
```

Comment: I tried but there is an error `.....index.php' on line 32: Undefined variable: class`

Comment: which comparison you did.

Comment: I tried to echo the url like this -` echo "<pre>", print_r($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). "</pre>";`

Comment: but I can't get the URL

Answer (score 0):

if You are ok with JS/Jquery solution here it is

HTML CODE:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=page-two">Page Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php?p=page-three">Page Page Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var PageName = getParameterByName('p');
    $("li a[href*='"+PageName+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

Working example is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/f16yqrpx/3/